# How to add a local variable automatically to every function

Tags: javascript

At the top of every one of my functions is this line:

```
var local = {}
```

This way I can scope my variables by saying

```
local.x = 1
local.y = 2
```

How can I change the prototype of all functions to include an empty object called 'local'?

Comment: X-Y problem.  Tell us what you're actually trying to accomplish, not the technique you're trying to use to accomplish it.

Comment: Isn't `var x=1, y=2` easier?

Comment: Function.prototype.someFunc = local.func ????

Comment: It's simply not possible...

Comment: var x=1 is easier, but I like explicitly scoping my variables using a local object.

Comment: You like it why? Did it ever occur to you to ask why you are the only person in the world doing this? Variables declared using `var` are *already* scoped to the function. There's no point in scoping them further within some local object. You're introducing a useless additional layer of indirection in dealing with your local variables. If your idea is that you want to put them in an object so it can somehow be shared or passed somewhere, then, well, they are no longer "locals".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you cannot (and it is very unusual to create local variables in an object rather than directly in the scope). This functionality is simply not a part of javascript.

Longer answer: you can do just about anything by loading your script as text, modifying the text, and then `eval`ing it. A better approach though would be to use the [SweetJs preprocessor](http://sweetjs.org/) and create a macro that overrides the function keyword to do this for you.

Comment: Or, you could parse your JS with Esprima and rewrite it to include your `locals` variable in each function. The fact that what you are trying to do involves transforming JS, or using a macro pre-processor, would hopefully give you pause.

Comment: Forgot about Esprima. Good one.